# Proof that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(x_n,x)=0$. Is it correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, solution-verification

Let $(x_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $x\in R$. I was attempting to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(x_n,x)=0$. Where $d : R\times R \to R^+$ is the distance function defined by $d(x, y)=|x-y|$. The following is my attempt at a proof.

Proof: Suppose that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$. We have to show that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $M>0$ such that for all $n>M$, we have that $|d(x_n,x)-0|=|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$. We know that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$. Thus for all $\varepsilon > 0$ we know that $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$. Hence, there exists an $M>0$ such that for all $n>M$, we have that $|d(x_n,x)-0|<\varepsilon$.

In the other direction, suppose that $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(x_n,x)=0$. We have to show that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, we have that $|x-x_n|<\varepsilon$. We know that $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(x_n,x)=0$. Thus for all $\varepsilon > 0$ we know that $|d(x_n,x)-0|=|x-x_n|<\varepsilon$. Hence, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have that $|x-x_n|<\varepsilon$.

Is the proof correct?

Edit: Got some variables wrong. Fixed them now.

Edit2: Wrote an L instead of an x. Changed that now.

Comment: Morally correct. You could write them more succinctly.

Comment: @tangentbundle what aspects would you suggest changing?

Comment: What is the definition of $d(x,y)$?

Comment: @StefanLafon It's the distance function. $d(x, y)=|x-y|$

Comment: In that case, isn't it the definition of $\lim x_n = x$ that $\lim d(x_n,x)=0$?

Comment: @StefanLafon The book I was learning from asked to prove that. I was just attempting to do that. Which isn't that difficult as the two definitions of convergence for sequences and function at infinity are quite similar.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few mistakes:

- What is the relation between $L$ and $x$? I assume $L=x$. So why to use two names?
- What is $\lim_{x\to \infty}d(x_n,x)$? Maybe you should use $n\to\infty$.
- Don't consider $x>M$. It's $n$ that has to be taken larger than $M$. The point $x$ is your limit, it's a fixed value during the proof.

Apart from this the proof is more or less correct. It's better to compare these two sentences:
$$ 
x_n\to x  \iff \forall_{\varepsilon>0}\exists_{N\in \Bbb N}\forall_{n>N}:|x_n-x|<\varepsilon,\\
d(x_n,x)\to 0  \iff \forall_{\varepsilon>0}\exists_{N\in \Bbb N}\forall_{n>N}:|d(x_n,x)-0|<\varepsilon.
$$
Now the only thing we have to observe is that $|d(x_n,x)-0|=d(x_n,x)=|x_n-x|$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was writing down the problem from the book and then the solution from my notebook. I confused the variables. I thought I corrected most of them but I see there are a few left. I’ll correct them as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very quick way to prove this. Any norm $\left\|. \right\|$ and clearly the absolute value, is a

continuous function.

Therefore $y_{n}=x_{n}-x\,\to\,0$ immediately implies $|y_{n}|\to 0$ i.e. $|x_{n}-x|\,\to\,0$ and we get the result!!